# Is it possible to combine facet_wrap() with stacked graphs?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data.frame EXAMPLE:

```
days <- c(1:3,1:3, 1:3)
countries <- c("USA", "USA", "USA", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan", "China", "China", "China")
cases <- c(30, 40, 50, 10, 12, 9, 22, 29, 33)
deaths <- c(3,4,5,1,2,1,2,3,4)


EXAMPLE <- data.frame(days, countries, cases, deaths)
```

I used facet_wrap() to plot multiple graphs, having days in the horizontal graphs and then "cases" on the Y-axis. I did the same but with "deaths" on the Y-axis.

```
library(ggplot2)

EXAMPLE %>%
 ggplot(aes(x=days, y=cases, color=countries, fill = countries)) +
 geom_line() +
 facet_wrap(~countries, scales = "free")

EXAMPLE %>%
 ggplot(aes(x=days, y=deaths, color=countries, fill = countries)) +
 geom_line() +
 facet_wrap(~countries, scales = "free")
```

Everything worked well, but I have this question:

Instead of having two files, one to each variable, is it possible to share the same X-axis but with different variables (Y)? So, in the end, I would like something like this image, but to each country: "deaths" below and "cases" above, or the opposite.

I really appreciate if someone can help :)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for a `facet_wrap()` approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
days <- c(1:3,1:3, 1:3)
countries <- c("USA", "USA", "USA", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan", "China", "China", "China")
cases <- c(30, 40, 50, 10, 12, 9, 22, 29, 33)
deaths <- c(3,4,5,1,2,1,2,3,4)
EXAMPLE <- data.frame(days, countries, cases, deaths)
#Reshape
EXAMPLE %>% pivot_longer(-c(days,countries)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=days,y=value,color=countries, fill = countries))+
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(.~name,ncol = 1,scales = 'free_y')
```

Output:

[image]

Or maybe `facet_grid()`:

```
#Reshape 2
EXAMPLE %>% pivot_longer(-c(days,countries)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=days,y=value,group=1,color=countries))+
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(name~countries,scales = 'free_y',switch = "y")
```

Output:

[image]

Or if more customization is needed:

```
#Reshape 3
EXAMPLE %>% pivot_longer(-c(days,countries)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=days,y=value,group=1,color=countries))+
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(name~countries,scales = 'free_y',switch = "y")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(face='bold',color='black'),
        axis.title = element_text(face='bold',color='black'),
        strip.text = element_text(face='bold',color='black'),
        legend.text = element_text(face='bold',color='black'),
        legend.title = element_text(face='bold',color='black'),
        strip.background = element_blank())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't want multiple lines on the same graph. I want exactly how my facet_wrap() example, but one variable above another.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`facet_grid`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html), with [`pivot_longer`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html):

```
EXAMPLE %>%
  pivot_longer(c(cases, deaths), names_to = "field", values_to = "value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = days, y = value, color = countries, fill = countries)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(countries), rows = vars(field), scales = "free")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: @Jones I'm glad you found an answer.  I'm curious, what was it about the `facet_grid` implementation that @Duck posted after my answer, that offered a better solution for you?